# mysql count query

Tags: mysql, count

I have a mysql table set up like this

```
id | refference_id | data
```

Is it possible to count the number of entries for each refference_id all in the query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  refference_id,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  refference_id
```

Comment: yes! thank you. i didn't select the name of the table in the query just the count(*) part that's why it wasn't working :<

Answer (score 0):

select count(distinct refference_id) as myResult from myTable;

Comment: not as i was looking for. it counts how many different refference_ids i have